# Trouble with struct() and arrays C++

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

So, i have to do this project for college. I have to write a program that manages the orders of a pizza restaurant. so far this is what i have done :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <cmath>
#include <locale>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
const int MAX_INGREDIENTES_PIZZA=10;
const int MAX_PEDIDOS=20;


enum TIngrediente
{
    TOMATE,
    QUESO,
    NATA,
    CEBOLLA,
    POLLO,
    HUEVO,
    SALAMI,
    ANCHOA,
    BACON,
    GAMBA
};

struct TPedido
{
    string nombre_cliente;
    int telefono;
    int numero_pedido;
    int numero_ingredientes;
    TIngrediente ingredientes;
};



typedef array<float, MAX_PEDIDOS> listado_pedidos;
const array<string, MAX_INGREDIENTES_PIZZA> TIngredientes2 = {{"tomate", "queso", "nata", "cebolla", "pollo", "huevo", "salami", "anchoa", "bacon", "gamba"}};

TIngrediente StrToIngrediente(string s);
string IngredienteTostr(TIngrediente c);
string tolower(string s);

string tolower(string s)
{
    string r = s;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i)
        r[i] = tolower(r[i]);
    return r;
}

TIngrediente StrToIngrediente(string s)
{
    s=tolower(s);
    int i;

     while (i < TIngredientes2.size() and TIngredientes2[i] != s)
        ++i;
    return (TIngrediente)i;
}

string IngredienteTostr(TIngrediente c)
{
    return TIngredientes2[c];
}

TIngredientes2 leer_ingrediente()
{
    TIngredientes2 r;

        for (int i=0; i<MAX_INGREDIENTES_PIZZA;i++){
            cin>>r[i];
            r[i]=tolower(r[i]);
        }
        StrToIngrediente(TIngredientes2);



        return r;
}

TIngredientes2 escribir_ingrediente()
{
TIngredientes2 s;
for(int i=0; i<s.size(); i++){
    cout<<s[i]<<endl;
}



return s;
}

TPedido leer_pedido()
{
    TPedido p;
    string ingredientes;
    bool ok=true;

    getline (cin, p.nombre_cliente);
    cin >> p.telefono;
    cin >> p.numero_pedido;
    cin >> p.numero_ingredientes;
    cin.ignore(100,'\n');
    //getline (cin, p.ingredientes);
    StrToIngrediente(ingredientes);

    //necesitamos inicializar la variable booleana
    if( numero_ingredientes > MAX_INGREDIENTES_PIZZA)
        ok=false;
    else if (numero_pedido > MAX_PEDIDOS)
        ok=false;
    else if (ingredientes != TIngrediente[i])
        ok=false;

    return p;
}
```

OK, But im having a few issues :

1) i have declared `TIngredientes2` as an array, but the compiler says to me `Tingredientes2` does not name a type.

2) I have managed to write the functions that transforms `String` in `TIngrediente` (enum) and viceversa, but now i have to make 2 functions to read keyboard input/write in screen and i dunno how to use those functions. I have writen something below but i dont know if it is ok.

3) When it comes to read keyboard input in `leer_pedido()` i dont know if that is ok because of the struct and most important, i have no idea how to use the boolean to say if the data introduced is correct or not.

4) The next fuction consist in storing the data from the last fucntion `leer_pedido()` in a list, and i have no clue.

I hope someone can help me

Comment: You declared `TIngredientes2` as an object, not as a type. It's an object of type `array<string, MAX_INGREDIENTES_PIZZA>`. And further in your code, you try to use it as an object in some places and as a type in others, i. e. you confuse the two categories.

Comment: The thing is that i havent studied objects yet, so when i declared ´array<string, MAX_INGREDIENTES_PIZZA>´ as a Typedef the compiler sends me another error. Im having a little trouble because the program is way bigger that what im used to do, so...

Comment: Here's how you declare a type:
`typedef array<string, MAX_INGREDIENTES_PIZZA> TIngredientes2;`

And here's how to declare an object of this type:
`TIngredientes2 ingredientes;`

Answer (score 0):

1)  Function can't return an object of type 'Ttingrediente2' if you haven't already made class of type 'Tingrediente2'.

In your function :

```
    TIngredientes2 escribir_ingrediente()
{
TIngredientes2 s;
for(int i=0; i<s.size(); i++){
    cout<<s[i]<<endl;
}
```

You're declaring variable 'Tingredientes s' and after it,you're printing it out on the screen but it hasn't got size (there are no elements inside s).

Try like this:

```
void escribir_ingrediente(array<string,MAX_INGREDIENTES_PIZZA> s)
{
for(int i=0; i<s.size(); i++)
    cout<<s[i]<<endl;
}
```

where you are passing already existing array to a function and it's printing out elements of s array.

2)  Just read more about enumerations,iterating over them and inserting new elements.

3)  You're using boolean variable on the beginning of testing your user's input.Something like:

```
bool good_Input = true; // suppose user's input is ok

if( p.numero_ingredientes > MAX_INGREDIENTES_PIZZA || p.numero_pedido > MAX_PEDIDOS) 
    good_input=false; // input is not good if there is more ingredients than max number of ingredients


if(good_Input) 
   cout<<"Input is good"<<endl;
else cout << "Input is not good"<<endl;
```

Therefore,you are leading boolean variable through your code so if there may be a mistake,you change it's value to 'false' and it will be 'false' to the end so you will know how to handle it further in code.

4)  Storing structure's data in vector is the most easiest way to do that:

```
vector<Tpedido> structuresVector;
sturcturesVector.push_back(leer_pedido());
```

leer_pedido function returns 'Tpedido' type so you can insert it in vector directly